# Is matrix multiplication by an invertible matrix one-to-one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Maybe I'm just not very experienced on the nitty gritties of matrix multiplication, but is the function $f(X)=AX$ where $X$ is a square matrix and $A$ is an invertible matrix one-to-one and onto? How about $f(X)=XA$? Intuitively the first one seems to satisfy the property, but the second one seems difficult to grasp.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then the linear map is bijective.

Comment: Yes, but how about the "inverse" multiplication? Also, $X$ is a matrix, not a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if $f(X) = AX$, then write $g(X) = A^{-1}X$, then
$$(
f\circ g)(X) = X, \text{ and } (g\circ f)(X) = X
$$
Do you see why this implies that $f$ is one-to-one and onto?

Comment: What about $f(X)=XA$?

Comment: @user54609 consider $g(X)=XA^{-1}$... clearly $f\circ g=g\circ f=\operatorname{Id}$

Answer (score 1):

Also, we can prove this claim by contradiction. Assume there exists a matrix $B$ such that
$$
A_1X=B,\ A_2X=B,
$$
where $A_1\neq A_2$. Then
$$
A_1X-A_2X=B-B=0 \Rightarrow (A_1-A_2)X=0
$$
Clearly, the rank of righthand-side is $0$. So the rank of $(A_1-A_2)X$ is also $0$. We know that invertible matrix preserves the rank of the multiplication. So the rank of $A_1-A_2$ is $0$ and hence $A_1=A_2$.

Therefore, $f(X)=AX$ is one-to-one.

Similarly, you can show $f(X)=XA$ is a one-to-one map.